# GPIO output value not changing

Tags: linux, permissions, embedded, gpio

I am trying to setup up a output GPIO pin on my Nitrogen6X board, but I can't change the file `value`.  I navigated to `/sys/class/gpio/` and I exported my pin (GPIO18) with `echo 18 > export`.  I was then able to change `direction` with the command `echo out > direction` and it seems like I should be able to change the `value` file the same way, with `echo 1 > value`, but this doesn't seem to be working.  I am logged in as root and the permissions on both the `direction` file and the `value` file are the same: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root`.

Does anyone have an idea why this would not be writing to this file?

Thanks so much for all of your help!

Comment: maybe there is another process that change the value of pin, are you sure this pin is free at all?  
You can use `lsof` to check the busy resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands that you have listed should work, if the gpio number is correct. While I have not worked with Nitrogen6X in particular, I have found out that Linux GPIO pin numbers often do not match the labels on the board. I advice trying to find out the proper mapping experimentally by watching all possible GPIOs:

```
cd /sys/class/gpio
for x in `seq 1 128`; do echo $x > export; done
```

ground the pin in question via 10k resistor, run:

```
grep . gpio*/value > /tmp/values0
```

connect the pin in question to Vcc via 10k resistor, run:

```
grep . gpio*/value > /tmp/values1
```

diff the files, and pay attention which pin has changed.